# debug already installed application on a real device

Tags: android

I can debug android application on a real device, but debugger first installs new version of the application.

Can I configure Eclipse (or any other IDE)  so that it does not reinstalls the application?

Answer (score 5):

As long as the application is signed by your keystore, you can attach the debugger to the device without reinstalling the new app.

> 1) Go to DDMS eclipse perspective.
>
> 2) You should see a list of attached devices on the left.
>
> 3) Each device should have a list of the debuggable applications that has installed
>
> 4) Select the app you want to debug, and press the green bug on the top left to start debugging it

Comment: the list of attached devices is empty :(

Comment: then you don't have an application that you can debug. Was the app signed with your debug key by the time you installed ? Do you have the app project imported into eclipse ?

Comment: The list of attached devices should be there anyway.  What if you type "adb devices" from the command line?

Comment: @EdwardFalk is right, the list of the connected devices should be there anyway, unless don't have your environment correctly set

Comment: I'll add: if "adb devices" doesn't show any devices, do "adb kill-server" and then "adb start-server" and try again.

Comment: I managed to see the device in the DDMS list and the application in it. When I press green bug, it prints "launching MyActivity" but does not switch to the Debug perspective, does not show application screen, and does not stops on breakpoints. When manually switching to Debug perspective, it shows application running some time, and then terminating.